# Multiple sort with Alpabet and count swift

Tags: swift

i have to to a multiple sort of Array, but it doesnot work

This is expected output. now this array is mixed up

```
struct Variant {
    var name: String
    var count: Int
}


let array = [
    Variant(name: "Ab", count: 12),
    Variant(name: "Ac", count: 10),
    Variant(name: "Ad", count: 8),
    Variant(name: "Ae", count: 0)
    Variant(name: "Bc", count: 55),
    Variant(name: "Bd", count: 45)]
```

i try do it like this, but it make priority on count and doesnot care about name

```
array = array.sorted(by: {
    ($0.count ?? 0, $1.name) > ($1.count ?? 0, $0.name)
})
```

Comment: show your expected output

Comment: This is expected output. now it is mixed up
let array = [
    Variant(name: "Ab", count: 12),
    Variant(name: "Ac", count: 10),
    Variant(name: "Ad", count: 8),
    Variant(name: "Bc", count: 55),
    Variant(name: "Bd", count: 45)]

Comment: I've posted an answer. If you wish to prioritise the alphabetical sort, just interchange the order of condition checks and you'll achieve the desired result

Comment: Tuple comparison is a good approach, but it should be `($0.name, $1.count) < ($1.name, $0.count)` for your purpose.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To sort based on multiple criteria, just include the conditions cascading each other based on priority.

EDIT: Thanks to Martin R pointing out the error, here's the revised code:

```
array.sorted(by: {
    //First layer of filter. Sorts based on alphabetic order
    if $0.name < $1.name {
        return true
    }
    else if $0.name > $1.name {
        return false
    }
    //Second layer. Sorts based on greater count
    return $0.count > $1.count
})
```

Input:

```
let array = [
    Variant(name: "Bd", count: 55),
    Variant(name: "Bc", count: 55),
    Variant(name: "Ac", count: 12),
    Variant(name: "Ab", count: 12),
    Variant(name: "Ad", count: 8),
    ]
```

After sort:

```
Variant(name: "Ab", count: 12),
Variant(name: "Ac", count: 12),
Variant(name: "Ad", count: 8),
Variant(name: "Bc", count: 55), 
Variant(name: "Bd", count: 55)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the result I want.  I must have a group by the first letter of the alphabet. For example, A, then from highest to lowest count in A. And then B, so on

Comment: Variant(name: "Ab", count: 55), 
Variant(name: "Ac", count: 12), 
Variant(name: "Ad", count: 8),
Variant(name: "Bc", count: 55), 
Variant(name: "Bd", count: 30)

Comment: I've edited the answer. Think this should satisfy your requirements. Like I said, you just need to perform your `if` checks based on sorting priority

Comment: This is not correct. Before checking the second layer, you must determine if the firsts layer determines the order. So you must check both `$0.name < $1.name` and `$0.name > $1.name` before comparing the counts.

Comment: This can be nicely achieved with tuple comparison, as already tried in the question, only that it should be `($0.name, $1.count) < ($1.name, $0.count)`

Comment: @MartinR Also, the OP wants to seem to sort based on 'ascending name' order and 'descending count'. That's why I suggested the current approach

Comment: @LokeshSN that's why you use $1.count (left hand side) and $0.count (right hand side) of the comparison as Martin suggested.

Comment: @LeoDabus Ah! Crazy how I didn't notice that! Almost a year later, I can now understand what it is. Gotta thank you for that :)

Answer (score 2):

Tuple comparison is a good approach to sort elements by multiple criteria, but you got the order of the tuple elements wrong.

The tuples are compared in “lexicographic order,” starting with the first (leftmost) element. In order to sort by name first, `$0.name` resp. `$1.name` must be the first tuple elements.

Therefore for ordering by name (ascending) first, and by count (descending) second, the sort function should be

```
array.sorted(by: {
    ($0.name, $1.count) < ($1.name, $0.count)
})
```